# Take a simple manual CMD prompt process and converting it into a BAT file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to convert a very simple manual CMD process into a BAT file.
So I am a pretty new but I am trying to piece together a manual cmd window process into a nice bat file for one click use for another user.

overview: my .exe file has to be opened as the same time as you give the name of the input file and the name of the desired output file.

Current process in CMD window looks like this:

```
C:/.../..../.../compute_upid.exe Input_Name.csv Output_Name.csv
```

Any idea on what commands in the bat file I can use?

here is what I have tried...

@echo off

set /p "input=INPUT.csv: "

set /p "output=OUTPUT.csv: "

C:/.../..../.../compute_upid.exe "%input%" "%output%"

Comment: `C:/.../..../.../compute_upid.exe Input_Name.csv Output_Name.csv` doesn't look like legal syntax.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.

All I know is...is that I put in my path with the .exe, I write the input file.csv name and my desired output file.csv and it gives me a csv with my output file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only that line, your .bat file will just be

```
@echo off
C:\path\to\file\compute_upid.exe Input_Name.csv Output_Name.csv
```

Remember, a batch file is just a list of statements to execute.

Comment: this does not work for some reason. I updated my question to include something that I tried. However when I try what you posted it says 'C:/../..' is not recognized as an internal or external command. operable program or batch file

Comment: I solved it. I didnt have double quotes because I have spaces in my path???all new to me